# how to set multiple bookmarks in a single page using java pdfbox library

Tags: java, pdfbox

I got a requirement to create bookmarks in existing pdf file, which may have multiple bookmarks in a single page, pointing to respective headings.

I was gone through a link which is explaining how to [Create Bookmarks](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreateBookmarks.java?revision=1709147&view=markup).  But it is explaining a bookmark for a page.

I'm Using pdfbox java library. Any sample code or links are appreciatable.

Answer (score 1):

The [`CreateBookmarks`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreateBookmarks.java?revision=1709147&view=markup) you refer to creates bookmarks with `PDPageFitWidthDestination` instances as destinations:

```
PDPageFitWidthDestination dest = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
dest.setPage( page );
PDOutlineItem bookmark = new PDOutlineItem();
bookmark.setDestination( dest );
bookmark.setTitle( "Page " + pageNum );
pagesOutline.addLast( bookmark );
```

`PDPageFitWidthDestination` is documented as

```
/**
 * This represents a destination to a page at a y location and the width is magnified
 * to just fit on the screen.
 *
 * @author Ben Litchfield
 */
public class PDPageFitWidthDestination extends PDPageDestination
```

On the other hand you want

> multiple bookmarks in a single page, pointing to respective headings.

In particular if you have multiple columns and different headings may end up right next to each other, you should use a different kind of destination, e.g.

- `PDPageFitRectangleDestination` which displays a given rectangle of a page, or
- `PDPageXYZDestination` which goes to a given point on the page and sets a given zoom value.

Adding an outline with such a destination focusing on the respective heading for each heading in your file should generate what you want.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  I'm a new bee here in pdfbox library.  Can you elobarate your answer or give sample code.  And can you suggest any document or link to get knowledge about pdfbox library and working with pdf documents in Java

Comment: To go into deeper detail with the isue at hand you need to tell us in which form you have the information where on which page those "headings" are. Concerning knowledge about PDFBox visit [their web page](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and download and study their examples. Concerning working with PDF documents in Java there is not much to say, it mostly depends on the library you choose to work with.